# TFS 2018 ERROR : TF401054

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I had restore `TFS database 2015(SQL 2014)` to `2018(SQL 2017)` successfully. and remapped it. But I got this error when I try to login to TFS

> TF401054: The requested service level property TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL did
>   not match the expected value. Team Foundation Server requires the
>   Dev16.M122.7 service level but the database currently implements
>   Dev14.M113.

Comment: Have you tried to set the [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) of the database to SQL 2016/2017? [TFS 2018 requires SQL 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirement-changes-tfs16?view=tfs-2018).

Comment: Thanks I changed compatibility level to SQL 2017 now. and restart the sql server. But no change same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have backups of your databases in a known good state; your best bet is going to be to bring back up a working TFS 2015 instance and then follow [modern upgrade documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)

The basic problem is that your team project collection databases have to be upgraded. Pointing TFS 2017 to TFS 2015 project collection databases without putting those databases through the normal process of attaching them (and thus upgrading them) isn't going to work. In a migration-based scenario, this is typically accomplished via the TFS admin console.

You may be able to go to the admin console and attach the databases, but my recommendation would be to bring up a working instance of your TFS 2015 environment and start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks I will try again

Comment: i'm going to uninstall all the versions and install again. my old tfs 2015 version is in another server. so now i'm going to install tfs 2015 into new server and restore old server database. after that new server upgrade to tfs 2018.

Comment: I had install TFS 2015 and SQL 2014 to new server and restore database and remaped it. but now i got this error                  TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the instance is specified correctly, that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.

Comment: @amnk This error can occur due to some edition . what are you used for your sql  edition ?

Comment: @amnk Please check:
Make sure you are the member of the `Administration Console Users.` Otherwise you cannot access the Admin Console.
Make sure the SQL Server is stated and available, and the network connectivity is OK.
Check the Service Account, make sure the Service Account has been added in SQL Server. and try it http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/04/solved-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/

Comment: Thanks @core114. I had uninstall and install again TFS 2015. after that i used upgrade wizard and set service account (admin User) it works. successfully restored. I think now i can upgrade it into TFS 2018 without error.

Comment: @amnk,  Glad to be of help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170751/discussion-between-core114-and-amnk).